# Pointers and structures

Tags: c++

I'm trying to wrap my head around pointers, references and addresses but every time I think I got it something unexpected pops up.

Why don't we need to dereference the structure to set a value in this example?

```
// pointer_tet.cpp
 #include <iostream>
struct example
{
    char name[20];
    int number;
};
int main()
{
   using namespace std;
   example anExample = {"Test", 5};
   example * pt = &anExample;
   pt->number = 6;
   cout << pt->number << endl;

   int anotherExample = 5;
   int * pd = &anotherExample;
   *pd = 6;
   cout << *pd << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: Thank you for your answers! What confused me was not being able to set *pt.number = 6.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you don't dereference to set a value.

Comment: Umm, you **are** dereferencing `pt`.

Comment: where do you think you do not derefrence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *are* dereferencing `pt`. You are doing:

```
pt->number = 6;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(*pt).number = 6;
```

The `->` operator provides a convenient way to access members through a pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I read this the other day, but it already slipped my mind. Thanks! Edit: I have to wait 10 min to set answer

Comment: The trick here is that `*pt.number` is `*(pt.number)` -- way back in the day, the precedence of `*` was set awkwardly, and `->` was added to make up for having to type `(*pt).number` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
anExample.number = 6;
```

OR

```
(*pt).number = 6;
```

Read cplusplus.com pointer tutorial might help.